# Overflow scroll/auto and height: 100%

Tags: css, scroll, height, overflow

I have a card on my page that needs to have an overflow scroll, and this card's height is '100%'.

It's working well with fixed height but I need it to be a dynamic height
I'm looking for a solution (maybe with flex ?) to allow the overflow scroll on it.

I tried a lot of things but nothing's really works.

Comment: Please edit the question and add your HTML and CSS code so we can best help you

Comment: 100% is a dynamic height

Comment: I know but the overflow scroll only works with fixed height. And I need a solution with dynamic height. Sorry if my question wasn't clear

Comment: overflow will work with height 100% - http://jsfiddle.net/fex1om39/

Comment: @Pete no it isn't. Only with fixed height

Comment: No what isn't, you keep repeating yourself and not listening.  Obviously it works as I have shown in my example.  Anyway as your question is off topic, I shall not spend any further time on this.  If you want more help, create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.  My guess is you do not know how to use percentage heights properly and it's not an overflow problem